# SequenceFile to .txt convert

Tags: java, hadoop

Is there any way to convert a Sequence file into .txt file? The sequencefile is generated after a hadoop job which is giving me an EOFException when i try to read it using SequenceFileReader, though the job completes successfuly. So i though i can copy the sequence file to my local system and then convert into txt format if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the file from seq to text is not a proper solution..try to look at the issue..and you can try something like this to read the key/value pairs -

```
public class SequenceFileReader {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Readeing Sequence File");
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/home/mohammad/hadoop-0.20.203.0/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/home/mohammad/hadoop-0.20.203.0/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));  
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path path = new Path("/seq/file");
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = null;      
        try {
            reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, path, conf);
            Writable key = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getKeyClass(), conf);
            Writable value = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getValueClass(), conf);
            while (reader.next(key, value)) {
                System.out.println(key + "  <===>  " + value.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

you can use "hadoop fs -text seqfile" command to convert seq file to text file though...

Comment: will there be any size difference after conversion between test.seq and test.txt? iF yes, arbitrarily or any by any equation?

Comment: @^ : usually text sequence files will have more compression, compared to image/audio/video sequence files. The compression depends on the content of the respective file. so, as far as i know, we can't give a fixed formula.